# In the action event method, it cant find my Jbutton objects. I'm trying to make a character select type thing and I cannot find a working solution

Tags: java, swing, awt, jbutton

Here is my code. The problem is at the very bottom in the action listener. You can tell I have all the button objects instantiated. I've tried making the button objects outside of the method. I really cannot find solution. Please help

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

 public class Select implements ActionListener {
 boolean shipSelect1=false;
 boolean shipSelect2=false;
 boolean shipSelect3=false;
 boolean shipSelect4=false;
 boolean shipSelect5=false;
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new Select().createGui();
        }
      });

}

 public void createGui() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Java Stocks");
    frame.setSize(700, 700);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.WEST);

    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    JButton button1 = new JButton("Dorito");
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.insets = new Insets(40, 40, 40, 40);
    panel.add(button1, c);
    button1.addActionListener(this);
    button1.setToolTipText("Your gonna fly a dorito in space son.");

    JButton button2 = new JButton("Otirod");
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    panel.add(button2, c);
    button2.addActionListener(this);
    button2.setToolTipText("(?rosnopS elbissoP).nos ecaps ni ortirod"); 

    JButton button3 = new JButton("Ship");
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 2;
    panel.add(button3, c);
    button3.addActionListener(this);
    button3.setToolTipText("Basic Ship");

    JButton button4 = new JButton("pihS");
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 3;
    panel.add(button4, c);
    button4.addActionListener(this);
     button4.setToolTipText("pihS cisaB");

    JButton button5 = new JButton("Good Ship");
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 4;
    panel.add(button5, c);
    button5.addActionListener(this);
    button5.setToolTipText("The ship is the best ship. Your not gonna");
}

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Object source = e.getSource();
     if(source == button1)
    {
        shipSelect1=true;

    } else if(source == button2)
    {
        shipSelect2=true;
    }
    else if(source == button3)
    {
        shipSelect3=true;
    }
    else if(source == button4)
    {
        shipSelect4=true;
    }
    else if(source == button4)
    {
        shipSelect5=true;
    }
    else{

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to read about **[scope](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-scope-in-java/)**. That property defines the visibility of variables.

A variable defined in a method is only visible within that method. So you have to move your buttons to class scope.

Meaning:

```
JButton button1 = new JButton("Dorito");
```

...

should go into the body of your **class**! Similar to what you have for all those guys:

```
boolean shipSelect1=false;
```

Note: you can still do all the init calls for those buttons in that method; you only have to **move** the declaration out of that method body.

Beyond that: the **real** answer is: don't try to learn Java with writing Swing UI applications. Start with the *real basics*; like [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html) - anything else will lead to frustration and waste of time. You are hardly able to crawl - yet you want to do hurdle racing.